# Looking for a tool similar to workflow slack for MS teams [Query management]

Tags: workflow, slack, microsoft-teams

We have a quick n clean query management UI on slack called workflows.
[image: Inquiry button]

Once clicked, we have a popup:
[image]

Once this is submitted, we get a chat message within that channel as an inquiry tagging important people. (Like a pseudo ticket). But most importantly the context of the message stays within the channel.

Do we have a way to replicate something similar for MS teams?
I had checked `halp` or `help desk` alternatives. Seems most creates tickets separately and not within the channel.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using power automate for teams. Its quite powerful!

Comment: Can you add some details about it, some link and its main features?